# MySQL Query for a simple table

Tags: mysql, sql

My table:

```
+----+---------+----------+--------+--------------+
| id | size    | quantity | status | customers_id |
+----+---------+----------+--------+--------------+
| 12 | 10_feet | 3        | active |            0 |
| 13 | 10_feet | 3        | active |            0 |
| 14 | 10_feet | 2        | active |            0 |
| 15 | 14_feet | 5        | active |            0 |
| 16 | 14_feet | 2        | active |            0 |
| 17 | 14_feet | 2        | active |            0 |
| 18 | 17_feet | 2        | active |            0 |
| 19 | 17_feet | 2        | active |            0 |
| 20 | 24_feet | 3        | active |            0 |
+----+---------+----------+--------+--------------+
```

Looking for query to show each size and a sum of the quantity.

```
10_feet  8   active
14_feet  9   active
17_feet  4   active
24_feet  3   active
```

Query that I am using is

```
SELECT *, SUM(quantity)  FROM`trucks` GROUP BY size;
```

But it shows only

```
10_feet   3 active
14_feet   5 active
17_feet   2 active
24_feet   3 active
```

Comment: `SELECT size, sum(quantity) FROM trucks GROUP BY size`?

Comment: After grouping, what would be the `active` column there for?

Comment: I used your query  "select a.size,sum(a.quantity),a.status from trucks a inner join trucks b on a.id=b.id group by a.size;" but it shows only  Size  Quantity  Status
10_feet  active
14_feet  active
17_feet  active
24_feet  active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
select a.size,sum(a.qty),a.status from table a inner join table b on a.id=b.id group by a.size
```

Comment: Size  Quantity  Status
10_feet  active
14_feet  active
17_feet  active
24_feet  active